# Please, don't do that!

Tags: typography, big-list

We often think that changing this or that will improve the layout or readability of a page or entire document, but sometimes we shouldn't. Which typographical choices does LaTeX make that we shouldn't interfere with?

Comment: Hi. It isn't clear what you are asking here. This is a Question and Answer site: what would be an answer to this question?

Comment: In my opinion, please, don't fill the background with colour, even grayscale tone.

Comment: This seems like a big-list question, so I edited it as such.  @Frederico, please make this question Community Wiki as per the [general consensus within the community](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-manage-big-lists).  (As an aside, I personally think this should be a one-post-per-answer style big-list.)

Comment: @Sigur - perhaps you should post it as an answer :)  (make sure to make it CW, I think.)

Comment: Frederico: Kindly expand your Q to be more specific and Hope @SeanAllred edit is what you are looking for ? "Which typographical choices does LaTeX make that we shouldn't interfere with?"

Comment: "LaTeX" doesn't make decisions about layout at all: particular document classes do. The thesis class I maintain for my university requires 1in margins and double spacing. This may be abominable, but I wouldn't interfere with it if you want the thesis office to accept your thesis.

Comment: @AlanMunn I think what OP was getting at was the standard LaTeX document classes.  The average user doesn't go messing with class files; that's left to people who actually design the document and, presumably, know what they're doing.  (And yes, getting your thesis office to accept your thesis is an undeniably *good thing*.)

Comment: How about putting the question an other way, say something like: Which typographical "features" should we not try to implement with LaTeX (unless we have to), because they are actually bad typography?

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the margins unless your governing institution says you absolutely have to.  Even if your boss says to change the margins, try to convince him that a wall of text simply isn't going to be read.

Comment: I've always found this kind of blanket advice misguided. The margins of a document are very dependent on the kind of document it is. Some documents may benefit from wide margins and some from narrower ones. There is no "one size fits all" answer to margins.

Comment: @AlanMunn - To a large extent I agree, but for documents that *you* write where nobody is telling you what to do, it is often best to live with one of the standard document classes available.  I've never come across a document that benefited from 2cm margins in any other way than saving paper.  I find people like 1in margins because they're *familiar*, not because they *look good*.

Comment: @SeanAllred Perhaps your answer would need to be stated less dogmatically. I believe it is perfectly fine to meddle with margins if you know what you are doing, or if you have a dire need to find a good compromise between a classic layout with asymmetric margins, and relatively smaller margins than in the medieval canon (let's face it, they waste paper in very long documents and they would *never* be accepted by fellow researchers).

Comment: @SeanAllred (Continued) Hence, I would suggest that it may be reasonable to discourage only margins that are the same on all four sides (like 1 inch), and symmetry (identical left/right and top/bottom margins) in two-sided documents.